# How to simulate Poisson arrival times if the rate varies with time?

Tags: r, poisson-process

Suppose we are to study a non-homogeneous Poisson process of 3 hour cycles in which:

> At the first hour, the arrival rate is 1.5 events / hr.
>
> At the second hour, the arrival rate is 2.1 events / hr.
>
> At the third hour, the arrival rate is 3.4 events / hr.

I would like to generate the time points (**not inter-arrival times**) of events observed in $3\times1000$ hours. How should I implement this in R?

**Edit1:**
Following jbowman's answer, I tried to verify the mean rate with

```
ia=diff(arrival_times)
t=arrival_times[2:length(arrival_times)]%%3
ia_bygrp=list(ia[which(0<=t & t<1)],ia[which(1<=t & t<2)],ia[which(2<=t & t<3)])
sapply(ia_bygrp,function(x) 1/mean(x))
```

The result was, unexpectedly (I only quote 1 result but I tried for 30+ times to reduce randomness)

```
[1] 1.892691 2.869797 2.116035
```

<strike>Why?</strike> See Edit2.

**Edit2:**
I tried to use larger rates: `rates = c (15.0, 21.0, 34.0)` for example. The arithmetic means were instead

```
[1] 21.64794 32.72656 15.59476
```

I believe it's because of the small number of occurrence `n_arrivals` in each hour which makes `runif(n_arrivals)` not-so-uniform. Any other solution?

**Edit3:**
Based on GeoMatt22's code with Octave (well, there is large variety here), I wrote another code to simulate the empirical rates $\lambda$.

Here is the code

```
rates <- c(1.5, 2.1, 3.4)
arrival_times <- c()
Nrep=10000
for (hour in 1:(3*Nrep)) {
  n_arrivals <- rpois(1,rates[1 + hour%%3])
  arrival_times <- c(arrival_times, runif(n_arrivals) + hour - 1)
}
arrival_times <- sort(arrival_times)

x=hist(arrival_times%%3,breaks=c(0,1,2,3),plot=FALSE)
bp=barplot(x$counts/Nrep,axes=FALSE,ylim=range(0,max(rates)*1.1),ylab="Observed rate / hr",main="Simulation for jbowman's answer")
points(bp,rates[c(2,3,1)],col='red',pch=20)
axis(side=2,at=seq(0,3.5,0.1),label=seq(0,3.5,0.1))
axis(side=1,at=bp,label=c("1st hours","2nd hours","3rd hours"))
```

and the histogram (red dot = true rates)
[image: Simulation for jbowman]

Pretty close. Apparently **counting occurrences in each hour** is not the same as **the reciprocal of mean hourly inter-arrival times**. [I think I have seen a question about the difference between the two but I could not retrieve it at the moment].

It turns out jbowman's answer can simulate well even using rates down to `rates <- c(1.5, 2.1, 3.4)/100`.

Comment: This is a coding question. I don't think OP has an issue with the conceptual understanding of the problem at all

Comment: @Aksakal the main question is about simulating a piecewise-homogeneous Poisson process. There are some R aspects in the edits, but I think the core question is statistical. (IMO this is worth keeping, if it is not a duplicate.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22, you are right, I'm retracting my close vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already several reasonable answers, but to try and add some clarity, here I will try to synthesize these, and do some verification on the resulting algorithm.

---

**Homogeneous Process**

For a [*homogeneous* 1D Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_point_process_on_the_real_line) with constant rate $\lambda$, the number of events $n$ in a time interval $T$ will follow a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)
$$n\sim\text{Poiss}_\lambda$$
And the arrival times $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ will be [i.i.d.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iid) uniformly through the interval
$$t_i\sim\text{Unif}_{[0,T]}$$
while the waiting times between events will be i.i.d. [exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)
$$\tau_i=t_{i+1}-t_i\sim\text{Exp}_\lambda$$
with [CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/cdf/info)
$$\Pr\big[\tau<\Delta{t}\big]=1-\exp^{-\lambda\Delta{t}}$$
So a homogeneous Poisson process can be easily simulated by first sampling $n$ and then sampling $t_{1:n}$ (or, alternatively sampling $\tau$ until $t=\sum\tau>T$).

---

**Inhomogeneous Process**

For an [inhomogeneous Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Defined_on_the_real_line) with rate parameter $\lambda(t)$ the above can be generalized by working in the *transformed* domain
$$\Lambda(t)=\int_0^t\lambda(s)ds$$
where $\Lambda(t)$ is the expected cumulative number of events up to time $t$. (As noted in [Aksakal's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276647/127790), and the [reference](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9959853397508521067) cited in [jth's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276593/127790).)

In the generalized approach we simulate in the $\Lambda$ space, where "time" is dilated so in the deformed timeline the Poisson process is now a homogeneous process with *unit* rate. After simulating this $\Lambda$ process, we map the samples $\Lambda_{1:n}$ into arrival times $t_{1:n}$ by *inverting* the (monotonic) $\Lambda(t)$ mapping.

Note that for the piecewise-constant rates $\lambda(t)$ here, the mapping $\Lambda(t)$ is piecewise linear, so very easy to invert.

---

**Example Simulation**

I made a short code in [Octave](http://octave-online.net/) to demonstrate this (listed at the end of this answer). To try and clear up questions about the validity of the approach for small rates, I simulate an *ensemble* of concatenated simulations. That is, we have 3 rates $\boldsymbol{\lambda}=[\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3]$ each of duration 1 hour. To gather better statistics, I instead simulate a process with $\boldsymbol{\hat{\lambda}}=[\boldsymbol{\lambda},\boldsymbol{\lambda},\ldots,\boldsymbol{\lambda}]$, repeatedly cycling through the $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ vector to allow larger sample sizes for each of the $\lambda$'s (while preserving their sequence and relative durations).

The first step produces a distribution of waiting times (in $\Lambda$ space) like this

[image: "L space" CDF comparison (exponential)]

which compares very well to the expected theoretical CDF (i.e. a unit-rate exponential).

The second step produces the final ($t$ space) arrival times. The empirical distribution of waiting times matches well with theory here as well:

[image: "t space" CDF comparison (mixture model)]

This figure is a little bit more busy, but can be interpreted as follows. First, the upper panel shows the component CDFs associated with a homogeneous Poisson process at each of the three $\lambda$'s. We expect the aggregate CDF to be a [*mixture*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixture) of these components
$$\Pr\big[\tau<\Delta{t}\big]=\sum_iw_i\Pr\big[\tau<\Delta{t}\mid\lambda=\lambda_i\big]$$
where $w_i=\Pr\big[\lambda=\lambda_i\big]$ are the mixing fractions.

For each component process, the expected number of samples is $\langle{n_i}\rangle=\lambda_iT_i$. Since the durations $T_i$ are equal, the expected mixing weights will then scale with the rates, i.e.
$$w_i\propto\lambda_i$$
The lower panel above shows the expected CDF obtained by mixing the components in proportion to their rates. As can be seen, the empirical CDF of the inhomogeneous simulation is consistent with this theoretically expected CDF.

---

**Example Code**

The following code can be run [here](http://octave-online.net/). (Note: the algorithm is only 4 lines; the bulk of the code is comments and verification.)

```matlab
%% SETUP
lam0=[1.5,2.1,3.4]; dt0=ones(size(lam0)); % rates and their durations
Nrep=1e3; lam=repmat(lam0,[1,Nrep]); dt=repmat(dt0,[1,Nrep]); % do replications (for stats check)

%% SIMULATION
L=cumsum([0,lam.*dt]); t=cumsum([0,dt]); % cumulative expected # events and time
Lmax=L(end); N=poissrnd(Lmax); % sample total # events
Lsmp=Lmax*sort(rand([1,N])); % sample event times (in "L space")
tsmp=interp1(L,t,Lsmp); % transform to "t space"

%% STATS CHECK
% "L space" waiting time CDF
dL=sort(diff(Lsmp)); p=(1:N-1)/N; % simulated
p0_L=1-exp(-dL); % exponential
h=plot(dL,p,'k',dL,p0_L,'r','LineWidth',1.5); set(h(1),'LineWidth',4);
axis tight; xlabel('dL'); legend('data','theory (exp)',4); title('L space CDF');

% "t space" waiting time CDF
dT=sort(diff(tsmp)); % simulated
wcmp=(lam0.*dt0)/(lam0*dt0'); pcmp=1-exp(-lam0'*dT); p0=wcmp*pcmp; % mixture
subplot(211); plot(dT,pcmp); ylabel('CDF'); title('Mixture Components'); axis tight;
legend(cellstr(num2str(lam0','lam = %0.1f ')),4);
subplot(212); h=plot(dT,p,'k',dT,p0,'r','LineWidth',1.5);  set(h(1),'LineWidth',4);
axis tight; xlabel('dt'); ylabel('CDF'); title('Aggregate');
legend('data','theory (exp mixture)',4);

% mean arrival rate
tbin=0.5:2.5; Navg=hist(mod(tsmp,3),tbin)/Nrep; bar(tbin,Navg,1);
hold on; plot(tbin,lam0,'r.'); hold off;
legend('observed (hist.)','theory (lam.)',0);
xlabel('hour'); ylabel('arrivals/hour');
```

---

As requested in the comments, here is an example of the simulated mean arrival rates (see also updated code above):

[image: Arrival rates (event counts per time-bin)]

Comment: I wonder if we could include calculate the empirical rate $\lambda_i$ from $\frac{1}{dT_i}$ (segregated into different time sessions)?

Comment: You just do a histogram on arrival times modulo 3 (see update). If the answer was helpful, feel free to upvote it :)  BTW the idea of concatenating the simulations (to get larger samples) should apply to any of the techniques suggested in the other answers as well.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer as it illustrated fully the conceptual and statistical aspects (even though the answer originated from others). The final histogram just made the whole answer complete to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods. For simple rate functions like yours I find the inversion approach to be the easiest. See algorithm 3 of [this paper](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~pasupath/PAPERS/2011pasB.pdf); it's 5 lines. Edit: and the algorithm is:

```
rates = c(1,2,3)
s = sum(rates)
cs = c(0, cumsum(rates))
R = function(t) {
  L = length(rates)
  t0 = floor(t)
  d = t0 %% L + 1
  return(s * floor(t / L) + cs[d] + (t - t0) * rates[d])
}
Rinv = function(y) {
  t0 = L * y / s
  return(uniroot(function(t) R(t) - y, c(t0, t0 + L))$root)
}
# Actual algorithm itself is only 2 lines.
x = cumsum(rexp(1000))  # desired nbr of points
y = sapply(x, Rinv)
```

If efficiency matters then you'd want to analytically invert `R(t)`.

Comment: Can you add the 5 lines? (To make your answer self-contained and avoid link-rot, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).)

Comment: FYI the linked reference is [Pasupathy, Raghu. "Generating Nonhomogeneous Poisson Processes." Wiley Encyclopedia of Operations Research and Management Science (2010).](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9959853397508521067)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward, thanks to the fact that the interarrival times of a Poisson process are exponentially distributed and the exponential distribution has the memoryless property.  (As an aside, note that if you are generating the time points, you are generating the interarrival times too, as they are just the differences between successive time points, and vice versa.)

One strategy is to generate the number of arrivals in each of the 3 x 1000 hours, then make use of the fact that the arrival times are uniformly distributed within each hour (thanks to the memoryless property.)  If you have, say, 3 arrivals in hour 1, you can generate the arrival times for that hour by generating three uniform variates over the hour.

You can ignore "crossing the hour boundary" effects, also because of the memoryless property of the exponential distribution.

For example:

```
rates <- c(1.5, 2.1, 3.4)
arrival_times <- c()
for (hour in 1:3000) {
   n_arrivals <- rpois(1,rates[1 + hour%%3])
   arrival_times <- c(arrival_times, runif(n_arrivals) + hour - 1)
}
arrival_times <- sort(arrival_times)
```

The first and last few arrival times are:

```
> c(head(arrival_times), tail(arrival_times))
 [1] 6.175204e-02 5.907350e-01 1.066275e+00 1.089332e+00 1.638492e+00 2.296899e+00 2.996753e+03 2.996817e+03 2.997005e+03
[10] 2.997376e+03 2.998619e+03 2.999689e+03
```

Comment: I tried to verify the mean of interarrival times. But the result is not as expected. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @user2513881 for such small numbers of samples, it is expected that the mean will vary a lot. To judge you could check the associated confidence intervals (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Confidence_intervals)). Or, more simply, just simulate a bunch of times (e.g. until $\sum n_\text{event}$ exceeds some threshold) and look at the ensemble statistics.

Comment: @GeoMatt22: "I only quote 1 result but I tried for 30+ times to reduce randomness". I further tried 10,000 simulations (each with 3,000 hours). The aggregated mean turns out to be `[1] 2.473990 2.587038 1.797931`. For the hours simulated with rate `3.4`, the range is `2.268 - 2.906`. Obviously CI will not cross the expected mean of 3.4. Running the simulation with 1 arrival for 1000 times is not the same as running another with 100 arrival for 10 times. This simulation algorithm does not converge to mean rate for small rates, seemingly.

Comment: @user2513881 OK, that makes sense. But does that mean the simulation algorithm is wrong? For a low rate **and** a short timespan, the exponential will necessarily have a severely truncated tail. Try the following: First simulate 1000 times, i.e. $\vec{t}_i$ for $i=1:1000$. Then concatenate the event times together, offset by $i-1$, i.e. $[\vec{t}_1,\vec{t}_2+1,\ldots ]$. When I do this, the concatenated $\Delta\vec{t}$ has the appropriate exponential PDF.

Comment: In [Octave](http://octave-online.net/) I did this: `lam=3.4; N=1e3; T=[]; for t0=1:N; n=poissrnd(lam); t=sort(rand(1,n)); T=[T,t+t0-1]; end; dT=diff(T); m=numel(dT); p=(1:m)/(m+1); dT=sort(dT); plot(dT,p,dT,1-exp(-lam*dT));`

Comment: I also observed that the code gives out converged rates even for rates as small as 1.5, if I make the process homogeneous, i.e. `rates <- c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)`. Strangely it doesn't when the rates vary with time. I also tried to **calculate mean after aggregation of $10000\times3000$ data** (using my understanding with your pseudocode) rather than **aggregating 1000 means as CI**. No luck.

Comment: user2513881 - To illustrate a problem you'll have with your algorithm, what interarrival time do you use in your estimation if there were no events in the interval?  That says there was an interarrival time of > 1 hour  for the process over the specified interval, but there's no actual number there to use when calculating a mean.  This is a more concrete way of illustrating @GeoMatt22's point above.

Comment: You can ignore "crossing the hour boundary" effects - what does this mean? I'm afraid this effect is very significant given the low intensities

Comment: @Aksakal - you can ignore the issue of having, for example, an event occurring at timestamp 2.9 with the next event's mean interarrival time being 1/3.4 hours and not having an event occur between timestamp 2.9 and timestamp 3, when the interarrival time changes to 1/1.5 hours.  You can do so because, conditional upon no event occurring in that 0.1 hour timespan (which we know it didn't, because we know how many events did occur in the hour and when they occurred) the time to the next event is now distributed exponential with mean 1/1.5 (ignoring the fact of another reset after 1 hour.)

Comment: ... the point being that you don't have to keep track of how much time there was between the last event and the end of the last interval in order to correctly generate the time of the next event.

Comment: @jbowman, the problem with your reasoning is this: you drew two events, then discarded one of them, by doing so you changed the distribution. I'll use your example: how do you know that no event has happened between 2.9 and 3? The only way to "know" it is by generating a next arrival time, and checking whether it pushes further than 3. Let's say it was 0.5 hours. Where are you going to place this event now? You're throwing it out, saying that "I know that nothing has happened between 2.9 and 3", then you proceed generating events in the next period. This is not Poisson process anymore

Comment: I gave an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276681/127790) using the "inversion method" (time dilation), and tried to add some verification to settle the disagreements in the comments here. (At least I *think* I got it right!) I think your approach is most likely correct: If the "edge crossing" was significant, then shouldn't it affect any Poisson model at its beginning (i.e. history would be needed to model the "first" event)? Perhaps you could add a demo doing as I did (cycling through the 3-hour sim. many times), to verify your solution's correctness?

Comment: @Aksakal - I know because there were (say) three events in the time between 2 and 3, the first happened at 2.4, the second at 2.6, and the third at 2.9.  Therefore there cannot be any events between 2.9 and 3, because I've already accounted for all three events that happened between 2 and 3.   Your final point is also incorrect - thanks to the memoryless property, we can, for example, generate an exponential time, and if it's greater than 3 (in this case), discard it and generate a new exponential time with the >3 rate and add "3" to it to get the time of the next event.

Comment: @jbowman, the memoryless property doesn't mean that you can discard the event. You're messing up with process, it's not Poisson anymore. I'd suggest you try to simulate the times with large sample and look at the event counts in each period, I bet that they'll be biased.

Comment: @Aksakal I tried to simulate with 10,000 replicates (totally 30,000 hours) and looked at the event counts with code modified from jbowman. I don't want to overload this comment, please refer to my Edit 3.

Comment: @Aksakal - No, they won't be biased.  They are as exactly Poisson distributed over each interval as the Poisson RNG allows.   I know this because I'm using a Poisson RNG to generate the number of events in each interval, so how could the event counts in each interval be anything but Poisson with the event-specific mean?  Furthermore, I am not discarding events.  I don't like saying this, because I've read more than enough of your work to know this is virtually never the case, but I suspect you may not have quite grasped the approach I'm taking, which does not involve interarrival times at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your intensities are so low that it's impossible to ignore the boundary effects. By that I mean that a time between the last event in the first hour and the first event in the next hour is covered by two Poisson (exponential) processes.

Method 1:
So, the simplest way to treat this (certainly, not the most efficient) is to construct the nonhomegenous intensity $\lambda(t)$ function, where $t$ is time. Next, step in time by one second (or a smaller interval), then generate the Bernoulli experiments, until you get to the end of the time.

Method 2:
However, a much better (faster) solution is to scale the time instead of scaling the intensity. Here's the idea. You have a homogenous Poisson process, BUT the time *speeds up* after one hour, NOT the intensity increases. Your clock ticks faster after the first hour by a factor of $\frac{2.1}{1.5}=1.4$ or $\frac{3.4}{1.5}\approx 2.27$. So, all you need to do is to generate a bunch of exponential arrival times, then compress the times after the first hour by appropriate factors.

Solution for Method 1

This is not R forum, and other folks might be interested in the solution, so here's a pseudo code:

```
function y = lambda(t)
  % nonhomegenous Poisson intensity
  % t - time is hours
  if t<1
    y = 1.5;
  else if t<2
    y = 2.1;
  else 
    y = 3.4;
  end if
end

function times = f()
  % times in hours of the event occurrences
  list times;
  dt = 1/3600;
  for t = 0 to 3 step dt 
    if rand() < lambda(t)*dt
      times.add(t);
    end if
  end
end
```

Solution for Method 2

```
function times = f()
  lambda = 1.5
  list times 
  t = 0
  do 
    dt = random_exponential(lambda)
    t = t + dt
    st = compress(t)
    if st<3
      times.add(st)
    end if
  while st < 3
end

% compress slow time to faster times after 1st hour
function st = compress(t)
  scale2 = 2.1/1.5
  scale3 = 3.4/1.5
  t2 = 1 + scale2;
  st = min(t,1) + (min(t,t2)-min(t,1))/scale2 + (max(t,t2)-t2)/scale3
end
```

Comment: (+1) I think this is the same approach as @jth, but the added explanation and generic pseudocode is much more clear.

Comment: If ``dt > 3`` in Method 2 then is the calculated rate correct?

Comment: @jth, that's a bug, you're right

Comment: I bit the bullet and tried my own hand at an answer, based on the time-dilation idea suggested by you and @jth. About the same, but I tried to add some verification to hopefully increase the OP's confidence in the result (and increase the non-R code diversity, I guess :) ).

Comment: You are trying to do this by generating interarrival times, but the OP said he/she did not want to generate interarrival times.  Also, you can ignore the boundary effects if you know how many events occurred in each hour, and you can find that out by randomly generating them, because they are distributed Poisson with the hour-specific rate.

Comment: @jbowman, OP wants arrival times, that's what's being returned

Comment: @Aksakal, yes you are right. I just don't want interarrival times as an end, but as a means it is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If Python is not a problem for you, I advise you to have a look at this new open-source library: [tick](https://github.com/X-DataInitiative/tick). Among others, it provides simulation and inference methods for point processes. You can find an example explaining the simulation of an inhomogeneous Poisson process [here](https://x-datainitiative.github.io/tick/modules/simulation.html#point-process-simulation).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am more inclined to use R.